# Proper way to destroy and re-create a VM with Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have followed the instructions here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead to get a local Homestead VM. It worked perfectly and I got Laravel up and running (serve homestead.app /public) and synced to a folder on my host machine (say ~/Code).

After trying to get Xdebug running, I messed up with a few configuration files (nginx.conf, php.ini, etc.). and thus, I destroyed that VM instance by running "vagrant destroy default". I then boot-up the VM again ('vagrant up') and ssh into the box. The files which I changed were reverted (expected) and the ~/Code directory had the Laravel sample app which I had created previously (again, expected as it was copied over from my host machine).

What I don't get is why the server was still running successfully and I could access my sample app from my host machine? I never ran 'serve homestead.app /public' again and yet the server was already running serving the /public folder. I find this very confusing.
So what’s the correct way to destroy and recreate Homestead VMs?

Cheers, SK.

Comment: I wonder if there was a cache with your login details, so when you created the new machine it auto-logged you in with those old (but same) credentials...if you're anything like me you tend to rebuild with the same login data LoL

Answer (score 0):

Destroy command does't remove box.
Here is docs. https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/destroy.html

To delete it:

```
homestead yourbox remove
```

if it doesn't work, try

```
vagrant yourbox remove
```

Comment: Whats confusing its not how to completely remove the box but why the nginx server was running after 'destroying' the box. From the vagrant docs 

"After running this command, your computer should be left at a clean state, as if you never created the guest machine in the first place."

So what i don't get is why the server is still running.

Comment: @skay- can you paste the link you read that part. Edit: it is the same link i guess.

Comment: clean state doesn't mean server will stop. don't confuse yourself.